# Upload photo to firebase storage if admin(me) give permission

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I have an app that users can upload photos. Uploaded photos will appear in homepage recyclerview via firestore adapter. How can I check if photo is ok or not and then make that photo appear at home page.

Photos are uploading firebase storage and firestore copy and paste photo's token url.

Comment: What do you mean through "check if photo is ok or not"?

Comment: I mean is it ok for my app theme. I just wanna approve or deny photo that users wanna upload

Comment: if he upload pornographic photo or something I will deny request. Sorry for my english btw.

Comment: What have you tired so far?

Comment: did you mean tried?

Comment: I didnt tried anything cause I dont know what should I do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process you're describing is quite broad, so I'll describe it at a high level below. You'll still need to do lots of legwork yourself to implement each step, but this is the best I can reasonably do on Stack Overflow.

You seem to have two types of photos in your application:

1. Approved photos that any user can see.
2. Unapproved photos that only application administrators can see.

So you'll need to make that distinction somewhere for each photo, having a way to identify approved and unapproved photos. You can make this split either in the Storage bucket already, or in the database (Firestore in your case). The latter allows a bit more flexibility, so let's focus on that.

You'll need to implement the upload-and-approval process like this:

1. Upload the photo from the user's app into the Storage bucket
2. Write metadata about the photo to Firestore

   1. This metadata needs to identify the photo, by its path or its download URL.
   2. This metadata identifies that this is a new photo, so it's not approved yet.
3. The application administrator can now read this metadata, and filter for photos that have not been approved yet.
4. The application administrator then approves each photo, by updating the metadata in the database. For example: by setting a field `approved` to `true`.

A few things to consider and keep in mind in this process:

- To ensure that regular users can only see approved photos, you can [use security rules and queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query).
- You'll also want to use security rules to make sure only the application administrator can approve a photo. Otherwise any regular user could also set the `approved` field to `true` in step 2.

Comment: I did something. When user posts something it will automatically sets to approve="false" (firestore field) , in the homepage there is firestore recycler that has whereEqualTo("approve",approve) query. If i sign in with admin account approve change to trueat the recycler. If I sign in with normal account approve change to false. So users only can see the true cards, I can only see the false cards. BUT when I launch the app again there is broken something that I didnt understand. Sometimes doesnt show up anything or even post is deleted from firestore it can still stay at homepage. HELP

Comment: Great job on making so much progress on this path already. It's hard to see what's going wrong from just the description you shared. Can you open a new question, and include the [minimal, complete/standalone code/rules/data in there that are needed to reproduce this new problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link please, as it contains lots of useful information on how to make it most likely we can help you)?